# macruby AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, macruby

I have a strange problem with adding observer for boundary time using AVFoundation AVPlayer.

```
 player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(someurl))
 player.play()
 player.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes([NSValue.valueWithCMTime(CMTimeMake(1,1))], queue: nil, usingBlock: -> { puts 'success' } )
```

When executing this code in XCode, it falls to the debugging assembler code on adding observer, while there is no error in the console. 
Has somebody faced such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it like this and it works:

```
__block AVPlayer* blockPlayer = self.player;        //player is already initialised and set up; 
__block id obs;

// Setup boundary time observer to trigger when audio really begins,
// specifically after 1/3 of a second playback

obs = [self.player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes: @[[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMake(1, 10)]]
                                             queue:NULL
                                        usingBlock:^{

                                           // Raise a notificaiton when playback has started
                                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PLAYBACK_STARTED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];

                                           // Remove the boundary time observer
                                           [blockPlayer removeTimeObserver:obs];
                                       }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation closely you'll see that this method returns:

> **Return Value**:
> An opaque object that you pass as the argument to removeTimeObserver: to stop observation.

and later that:

> **You must retain the returned value as long as you want the time observer to be invoked by the player.** Each invocation of this method should be paired with a corresponding call to removeTimeObserver:

Your issue is that you aren't retaining the returned value of the method, you are simply calling the method, therefore the time observer is not being invoked by the player.

Using a __block variable should actually work here

```
player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(someurl))
player.play()

__block id observer = player.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes([NSValue.valueWithCMTime(CMTimeMake(1,1))], queue: nil, usingBlock: ->
{
    puts 'success'
    player.removeTimeObserver(observer) // IMPORTANT, but careful. Read below*
} )
```

**below** *: As Apple stresses, you need to call removeTimeObserver, and the place that makes the most sense to me would be in the completion block, but, at least in Obj C and Swift and most other languages, this would cause a retain cycle. You can get around this in Obj C and Swift by declaring the observer and the player as [block variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6) so that you can safely reference them from inside the block.

If you can find some other place to safely call the removeTimeObserver method then you don't have to worry about that though.

Anyways the above code will execute the block when the player is 1 second into the song/video.

Also note that:

> AV Foundation does not guarantee to invoke your block for every interval or boundary passed. AV Foundation does not invoke a block if execution of a previously invoked block has not completed. You must make sure, therefore, that the work you perform in the block does not overly tax the system.

which I don't think applies to you, but may apply to someone else who has added multiple time intervals/boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it really needs some queue to be passed as a parameter

try this:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

[player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:[NSValue.valueWithCMTime(CMTimeMake(1,1))]
                                  queue: myQueue
                             usingBlock: -> { puts 'success' }];
```

Comment: no, passing nil to the queue causes the main queue to be used, as per the documentation